# Using file-input with accept image to access webcam on laptop

Tags: html, forms

This most probably is a duplicate, please point me in the right direction:

I know how to use a file-upload input type=file with accept=image to allow fileupload of images from mobile devices.

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
```

I would like to make this work on a Laptop just like on any other mobile device. Browser-Vendors still open up a Choose-File-Dialog where I would expect a "Choose-Source"-Dialog on mobile-devices.

I know that this is a thing that Browser-Vendors will have to solve, but in the meantime the question is: Is there any framework that emulates such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

http://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/ for other media capture examples.

If you don't need IE support then you could try the [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

```
// A lot of other options are available - check out the constraints. 
const constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

const video_stream = document.createElement('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {

  video_stream.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video_stream.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    document.body.appendChild(video_stream);
    video_stream.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

You can capture a frame and then append it to a canvas for preview and from there export it to .png/.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) I tried the links in the example but could not get the camera of my laptop to work... I am looking for a way to make my desktop-chrome use the camera of my laptop

Comment: I updated my answer so you could try with the mediaDevices.